# OpenStreetMap queries on history?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I would like to get a list of modifications on the OSM database, in a given bounding box, between two given dates and impacting a given set of tags.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Any command-line tool, webapp such as Overpass Turbo, or query API such as XAPI?

I have seen it's possible to get history of a map by its location and zoom level (example: http://www.openstreetmap.org/history#map=16/45.9605/5.3391), but this return groups of modification that contains modifications outside of the current map).

I have also seen a [history browser](http://osm.virtuelle-loipe.de/history/) to browse history of a given object (node, way or relation).

Comment: crosspost: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130907/osm-queries-on-history

Comment: Did you already look at Overpass API's [attic](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Attic_data_.28.22date.22.29) and [diff](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Delta_between_two_dates_.28.22diff.22.29) statements?

Comment: this 'diff' is exactly what I was looking for, cause the data I want to update are associated to an OverpassTurbo script. The problem is my scripts are in Overpass XML language, and I don't know where to write the 'diff' expression. For example, I have:
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="900">
  <union>
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="highway"/>      
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
</union>
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>

Comment: after a little test, it works to do <osm-script output="xml" timeout="900" date="2012-09-14T15:00:00Z"> but if I try <osm-script output="xml" timeout="900" diff="2012-09-14T15:00:00Z, 2012-10-14T15:00:00Z">, I get the following error: Unknown attribute "diff" in element "osm-script"

Comment: `diff` translates to `<osm-script date="2012-09-21T15:00:00Z" from="2012-09-14T15:00:00Z" timeout="240">`  in Overpass XML. To find out what an Overpass QL query looks like in XML format, you can always use the [convert form](http://overpass-api.de/convert_form.html) or use the same feature from within overpass turbo.

Comment: yes! you are right, I forget to use the convert function to find the equivalent. Thanks a lot! I think this kind of request answer well in my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution we found is to use Overpass-Turbo "diff" functionnality.

Here is the XML script I use to get changes on roads in a given bounding box, between 2 dates:

```
<osm-script date="2014-09-21T15:00:00Z" from="2012-09-14T15:00:00Z">
  <union>
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="highway"/>
    <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
  </union>
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

And here is the equivalent in Overpass QL:

```
[diff:"2012-09-14T15:00:00Z","2014-09-21T15:00:00Z"];
(
  way["highway"]({{bbox}});
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Overpass' *Attic* and *Delta* feature might help you. It allows you to query historic data. You can expand any standard query with those additional filters.

There is some documentation on that topic http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Attic_data_.28.22date.22.29